# Oracle Apex - Create / Pass / Set Interactive Report (IR) Filters as parameters through URL

Tags: oracle, filter, report, oracle-apex, interactive

### **Scenario**

1. Tried to add Oracle Apex **Interactive Report Filters** using URL.
2. Followed official doc syntax : **[Oracle installation doc - 8.4.3 Linking to Interactive Reports](https://docs.oracle.com/database/apex-5.1/HTMDB/linking-to-interactive-reports.htm#HTMDB30108)** yet, could not find straightforward URL syntax for **creating IN or CONTAINS operators filters ( in Oracle Apex interactive report ) through URL .**

Answer (score 6):

### **Oracle Apex - Create / Pass / Set Interactive Report (IR) Filters as parameters through URL**

---

**Credits** : [1](https://www.oracle-and-apex.com/set-interactive-report-filter-with-url-parameters/) [2](http://oraclemasterminds.blogspot.com/2016/04/set-interactive-report-filter-with-url.html)


 **STEP 1 - Define static id for interactive report region**

[image]

---

**STEP 2 - Change URL syntax to contain - Report ID | Filter | COLUMN NAME** :

( **Example 1** : will add interactive report **filter** with **IN** operator   )

```
http://mywebsite.com/ords/f?p=103:2:::::IR[MOS]IN_SR_COMPANY:\Coca Coba,Gudai Exchange Holdings\
```

Where :

- **IR** - Prefix is mandatory
- **[MOS]** - Static Id of Interactive Report.
- **IN** - interactive report filter **IN** operator ( see operator list below)
- **SR_COMPANY** - interactive report column name.
- **\Coca Coba,Gudai Exchange Holdings\** - value of filter ( in this example : 2 companies names ).
  [image]

Result:

[image]

( **Example 2** : will add interactive report **filter** with **contains** operator and will **clear previous filters**   )

```
 http://mywebsite.com/ords/f?p=103:2::::CIR:IR[MOS]C_SR_COMPANY:\GMC Sport Company\
```

Where :

- **CIR** - cleans previous filters
- **IR** - Prefix is mandatory
- **[MOS]** - Static Id of Interactive Report.
- **C** - interactive report filter **contains** operator ( see operator list below)
- **SR_COMPANY** - interactive report column name.
- **GMC Sport Company** - value of filter ( in this example : 2 companies names ).

Result:

[image]

---

**LIST OF VALID OPERATORS** ([oracle apex official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/19.1/htmdb/linking-to-interactive-reports.html#GUID-B917CEB3-A0B9-414B-A90A-7B44DD15EA67)) :

**Valid operators include:**

**C** = Contains

**EQ** = Equals (this is the default)

**GTE** = Greater than or equal to

**GT** = Greater Than

**LIKE** = SQL Like operator

**LT** = Less than

**LTE** = Less than or equal to

**N** = Null

**NC** = Not Contains

**NEQ** = Not Equals

**NLIKE** = Not Like

**NN** = Not Null

**NIN** = Not In (escape the comma separated values with a leading and trailing backslash, )

**IN** = In (escape the comma separated values with a leading and trailing backslash, )

**ROWFILTER** = Row Text Contains (this searches all columns displayed in the report with type STRING or NUMBER)